# How to serve static files using Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to write server side application using Swift and Vapor framework. However, I can't figure out, how to serve static files using Vapor. It's not enough to just move them to the `Public` or `Resources` directory.

How can I do that?

**UPD.**
I performed steps which Tanner Nelson suggested but it still doesn't work.

What I tried so far:

1. `vapor build` and `vapor run` (using Vapor Toolbox v0.6.1).
2. `./build/debug/App` from root directory (which contains `Package.swift`).
3. Run in Xcode 8 beta after editing scheme as Tanner Nelson suggested.

In all this cases I get error 
`{"error":true,"message":"Page not found"}`

I have file `vapor_logo.png` inside a `Public` folder and also the same file inside `Public/images/` folder. I try to request it and it fails. Requests that I made: `http://localhost:8080/image/vapor_logo.png` and `http://localhost:8080/vapor_logo.png`. However, other routes work fine.

**UPD 2.** Well, that was all my mistakes. First, file that I think was called `vapor_logo.png`, actually was called `vapor-logo.png`. Second, case matters when you make a request. I also tried to request file with name `IMG_8235.JPG` but write file extension as `jpg`, so got an error.

So, just to recap: if you experience the same problem as me, follow the Tanner Nelson's answer and make sure that name of requested file **exactly** matches name of file on disk.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Vapor folder structure from [Docs](http://docs.qutheory.io):

```
VaporApp
├── Package.swift
├── Resources
│   ├── Views
│   │   └── hello.leaf
├── Public
│   ├── images (images resources)
│   ├── styles (css resources)
└── Sources
    └── ...
```

Any files in the `Public` folder will be served by default if no routes have been registered that conflict with the file name.

For example, if you have a file `Public/foo.png` and the following `main.swift` file:

```
import Vapor

let drop = Droplet()

drop.get("welcome") { request in
    return "Hello, world"
}

drop.serve()
```

A request to `localhost/welcome` would return `"Hello, world"` and a request to `localhost/foo.png` would return `foo.png`.

If this is not working properly, it's likely that your working directory is not configured properly. This can happen if you are running your project from Xcode or you are running it from the command line from a folder that is not the root directory of the project.

To fix Xcode, go to `Schemes > App > Edit Scheme > Run > Options > Working Directory > [x] Use Custom Working Directory` and make sure the directory is set to the root of your project (where the Package.swift resides).

[image: Xcode working directory]

To fix when running from the command line, make sure you are running the application from the root directory. i.e., the run command should look something like `.build/debug/App` since the `.build` folder is located in the root directory.

Comment: Thank you for answer! However, it still not working. I made an update to original question.

Answer (score 12):

For me, it was uncommenting this line in `configure.swift`:

```
middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public` directory
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [the answer with `FileMiddleware`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459632/442427), sometimes one needs to serve a specific file instead of the whole `Public` directory, that's where using `request.fileio.streamFile` could help:

```swift
app.get("file") { (request: Request) in
  // stream the file
  request.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(
    request.fileio.streamFile(at: "/your/filepath")
  )
}
```